# Using bin/console gets AppFixtures::load error

Tags: symfony

```
Compile Error: Declaration of App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures::load(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager) must be compatible with Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface:  
  :load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager)
```

The above error is coming when I run composer install or bin/console (anything)

I have a working project but had to transfer to a new server. The main differences are apache version and php version (formerly 7.3.16 now 7.3.22)

I have tried:
*composer dump-autoload
*checked php dependancies
*confirmed .env settings
*rm -rf vendor/* and reinstall
*dev and prod environments in .env

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212113/whats-the-compatibility-between-objectmanager-and-entitymanagerinterface-in I used --no-dev and it installed, but would still like to know why it broke

Comment: `load` method argument needs `ObjectManager` from `Doctrine\Persistence\` namespace, but in your implementation class you define `ObjectManager` from other namespace. make sure the namespace of the type-hint same with the interface

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @indra you are right, since Doctrine 2.1.2 the Doctrine/Common was removed so any repos/fixtures using those failed. After updating them all in app, it worked.